# How can I run a method repeatedly for a set amount of time?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I've been using Schedule Executor service to run my code every 3 seconds. Is there a way to run it every 3 seconds for 24 hours in my case? My code looks something like this. It isn't important what it does so I've just removed it all. The only part I care about is one `List<String>` and the reason for that is after this 24 hour period I would then like to do some more stuff with this list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        
        // nonImportantVariables here

        List<String> importantList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        public void run() {
            //Not important code
    }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // AFTER 24 HOURS I WOULD LIKE TO PERFORM TASKS ON IMPORTANT LIST
    }
}
```

I've thought about adding a loop so it runs 28,800 times (that is how many 3 seconds are in 24 hours) but this seems a silly fix around and also I'd run into the issue that this wouldn't account for how long the code takes to run so would end up being more.

A second idea I had was the first time the iteration is run I can use a Date object. Using this Date object I could somehow add 24 hours onto this and have some method that compares the current Date object to the Date object at first iteration + 24 hours.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation of Schedule executor service where I can set how many times to run a command. Any improvements to either of these ideas or a different solution is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why not schedule another job that will starts 24 hours later and will shutdown the previous service?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! So If I set a delay of 24 hours from the first start of my program it will just trigger then and do things on my list. Would this stop my first service automatically or will I need to do anything special?

Comment: Just call the appropriate `shutdown` method of the service you want to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another scheduler and in it you can submit another task that would run just once with a delay of 24 hours and it will do 2 things.

1. shutdown the first scheduler and that will stop the execution of your original task.
2. handle the processing of your list

Comment: So in sort of pseudo code it will look something like this
`ScheduledExecutorService ses2 = new....
public void newMethod(){
shutdown my old service,
Process my list,
shutdown this service,
re open my old service,
delay for 24 hours?,
}`

Comment: Yes, except the last part that you want to run the whole 24 hour process continuously? you can do so, but you didn't describe it as what you wanted to do in your question

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. It might help if I give you a little bit of context. I'm reading stack traces into a list every few second. I want to put all these in a list then after 24 hours do some things with them. After I've finished processing these lists I want to then empty this list, and read things into again every few seconds for the next 24 hours and repeat.

Comment: I see. Than, I might suggest a different design. You create a scheduler, and have one task scheduled to run every 3 seconds after the previous run ended (not 3 seconds after the previous run started). On the first run you write the time instant when you started and write your stacktrace into the list. after that you check if 24 hours elapsed and if not  just add to the list. If 24 hours elapsed, then you handle your list, empty it and write the current time instant. And so on.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend to look at MgntUtils Open source library, written by me. It could actually help you very much. First of all, it has a utility that smartly filters stacktrace and keeps all the relevant info but shortens the stacktrace significantly. Also, There is a lifecycle management - customized schedulers that already do what you want to do, with the examples in the code. Here is the link for Javadoc: http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/

Comment: and here is the link in Javadoc for lifecycle management explanations: http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/backgroundrunner/package-summary.html. Here is the link for staktrace filtering method:http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#getStacktrace-java.lang.Throwable-boolean-java.lang.String- (note that you can filter stacktrace from exception in the code or from stacktrace text from logs).

Comment: And here is the link to the article that describes the library and points to the links where to get it from: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/ And finally here are the links where to get it as well: GITHUB - https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases and as maven artifact: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils

Comment: That actually looks incredibly useful for what I'm doing. My whole utility that I'm currently working on is reading exceptions from log files, seeing where they've come from and writing unique stack traces to some file/database. My current code can do all that from a Log file but I'm just adapting it so that it will work in live Log files and print the results once a day. I'll give it a read and hopefully will be able to implement it! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. I have a small favor to ask. If you end up using my library, please write a feedback on feedback section of the article about the library that I listed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234027/discussion-between-connor-gill-and-michael-gantman).